# How do I achieve the section-wise (home, about, work etc) background formatting similar to the one in the mentioned website?

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

Website: [wadegarett.com](http://www.wadegarrett.com/)

I am trying to use Zurb-Foundation 5 to build a similar kind of website. Does Foundation 5 have any classes which can achieve similar formatting? I found the "section-container" class in Foundation 4 documentation and used the following code:

```
<section id="about" class="section-container">
        <h1>Hello There!</h1>
        <h3>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</h3>
    </section>
```

It kind of works but I am not able to find any documentation for sections in Foundation 5. Is it okay to use this?

How do I define the height of each section?

How can this be done using normal CSS styling?

Comment: Not sure exactly what it is you want, I'm viewing from my phone right now so I can't see the desktop page of the site you're referring to. Can you add a screen shot? I use foundation 5 a lot, great stuff... It's primarily a grid system though so for a lot of stuff you'll have to code it yourself. But a little more detail would be helpful!

Comment: actually, I would have added a snapshot if I could have. But, I don't have enough reputation yet. I was asking about how the color of the background changes for the different sections, and how the dimensions of each section is defined- whether they adjust automatically with the content or are they of fixed heights?

Comment: Just updated my answer, it should work the way you want it now! Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was curious enough to go to my laptop and I think what you're looking for is Foundation's Magellan function:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/magellan.html

You can mix that with their Topbar function and you have the navigation system you're looking for.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html

The background effect is just a bunch of div's with different coloured (I'm Canadian haha) backgrounds.

We'll need to add a height of 100% to a couple things, the navigation bar will always have to be fixed though, and we'll have to add a padding of the height of the navigation bar to our div's.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .html, .body { height: 100%; } 
    .navigation { position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 40px; background: #ccc; }
    .home, .work { background: #fff; }
    .about, .contact { background: #ddd; }
    .wrap { width: 100%; min-height: 100%; padding-top: 40px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="navigation">...your sticky nav would go here...</div>
<div class="wrap home">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap about">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class=" wrap work">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap contact">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
            <p>Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```